# Making a Sierpinski triangle using fractals, classes and swampy's TurtleWorld - Python

Tags: python, fractals

I have this Python code:

```
import math, random, sys
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *

world = TurtleWorld()
Rasmus = Turtle()
Rasmus.delay = 0.000002

class rule(object):
        def __init__(self):
                self.rule={} #we make an empty dictionary

        def newrule(self,leftside,rightside):
                self.rule[leftside]=rightside #we fill the dictionary

        def expand (self,oldlist,depth):
                if depth <= 0:
                        return oldlist 
                newlist=[] # we make an empty new list
                for i in oldlist:
                        if i not in self.rule:
                                newlist.append(i)
                        else:
                                newlist.append(self.expand(self.rule[i],depth-1))
                return newlist

class command(object):
        def __init__(self, cmd, length):
                self.cmd = cmd
                self.length = length

        def execute(self, turtle, length):
            if self.cmd=='lt':
                    lt(turtle, int(self.length[0]))
            if self.cmd=='rt':
                    rt(turtle, int(self.length[0]))
            if self.cmd=='fd':
                    fd(turtle, length)
            if self.cmd=='bk':
                    bk(turtle, length)
            if self.cmd=='scale':
                    length = length*float(self.length[0])

class Fractal(object):
    def __init__(self, rules, commands, start, length, depth):
            self.rules = rules
            self.commands = commands
            self.start = start
            self.length = length
            self.depth = depth

    def draw(self, oldlist):
            for i in oldlist:
                    if type(i) == list:
                            self.draw(i)
                    else:
                            cmd = self.commands[i]
                            cmd.execute(Rasmus, self.length)

def read():
    files = open('sierpinski2.fdl')
    commands = {}
    r = rule()
    for line in files:
            line = line.strip()
            oldlist = line.split(' ')
            if oldlist[0] == 'start':
                    start = oldlist[1:]
            elif oldlist[0] == 'rule':
                    r.newrule(oldlist[1], oldlist[3:])
            elif oldlist[0] == 'cmd':
                    cmd = command(oldlist[2], oldlist[3:])
                    commands[oldlist[1]] = cmd
            elif oldlist[0] == 'length':
                    length = int(oldlist[1])
            elif oldlist[0] == 'depth':
                    depth = int(oldlist[1])
    return Fractal(start, r, commands, length, depth)

re = read()

print re.commands.keys()

length = re.rules.expand(re.start , re.depth)
re.draw(l)


wait_for_user()
```

which should extract information from a sierpinski.fdl file, which looks like this:

```
start F L F L F L

rule F -> F L F L F L F F

length 8

depth 5

cmd F fd

cmd L lt 120
```

My problem is that when I run this, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Python27\PythonScripts\swampy-2.1.1\swampy\Projekt del 2.py", line 81, in      <module>

   print re.commands.keys()

AttributeError: 'rule' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I know that the problem lie in the:

```
re = read()

print re.commands.keys()

length = re.rules.expand(re.start , re.depth)
re.draw
```

Part of the code, where I enable the execution of the program, but I can't seem to fix it.

I am using python 2.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read() function returns this `Fractal`

```
return Fractal(start, r, commands, length, depth)
```

but the signiture of `Fractal.__init__` is

```
def __init__(self, rules, commands, start, length, depth):
```

So it appears that you've swapped the order of the parameters.